# What's happening that my I2C sensor is high on SDA when it might be low, as SCL, when in the time pause between bytes?

Tags: sensor, i2c

I'm using an HDC1080 clone (original by Texas Ins.) temp/humidity sensor which communicates via I2C with an Arduino. Each measurement is 16 bits long and to save its data, you must read first the 8 MSB and later the 8 LSB of each register (there's one for temp and another one for hum).

The first issue was that randomly, it showed me the less significant byte like a 16-bit-word instead of a 8-bit-word, like this

[image: 16-bit_instead_of_8]

Taking a look at the scope, it could be watched that the mistake occurs when the SDA is high at the time SCL is low in the lapse between bytes, as the pic shows:

[image: issue]

It is happening randomly and sometimes in both registers, sometimes just one, but the interesting thing is that it only happens at the beginning of the second byte got from the same register.

Is it any problem with my sensor? How can I try to solve this situation?

EDIT: This is my Arduino code:

```
#include <Wire.h>

#define HDC 0x40 //Sensor address

int16_t humrawvalue;  //Raw data value, MS byte = valmsb, LS byte = vallsb
int16_t temrawvalue;  //Raw data value, MS byte = valmsb, LS byte = vallsb
int8_t humvalmsb, humvallsb;  //Raw 8-bit byte of humidity
int8_t temvalmsb, temvallsb;  //Raw 8-bit byte of temperature
int incomingByte = 0; //Action input

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Hello");
  Wire.begin();
}

void loop() {  
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    // read the action input:
    incomingByte = Serial.read();

    // say what you got:
    Serial.print("I received: ");
    Serial.println(incomingByte, DEC);
  }

  if (incomingByte == 49){    //ASCII code for number 1
    Wire.beginTransmission(HDC);
    Wire.write(0x00); //0x00 is the temperature register, 0x01 is the humidity one
    Wire.endTransmission(true);
    delay(200);

    Wire.requestFrom(HDC,4,true); //It asks for 4 bytes, 2 bytes per register
    if(Wire.available()){
      Serial.println("     ");
      Serial.println("Measuring: ");
      temvalmsb = Wire.read();
      temvallsb = Wire.read();
      humvalmsb = Wire.read();
      humvallsb = Wire.read();

      Serial.println("====TEMPERATURE====");
      Serial.print("MSB: "); Serial.println(temvalmsb, BIN);
      Serial.print("LSB: "); Serial.println(temvallsb, BIN);
      temrawvalue = temvalmsb <<8| temvallsb; //Locates each byte in its proper place
      Serial.print("Temp: "); Serial.println(temrawvalue, BIN);

      Serial.println("====HUMIDITY====");
      Serial.print("MSB: "); Serial.println(humvalmsb, BIN);
      Serial.print("LSB: "); Serial.println(humvallsb, BIN);
      humrawvalue = humvalmsb <<8| humvallsb;
      Serial.print("Hum: "); Serial.println(humrawvalue, BIN);

      Serial.println("     ");
      delay(3000);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not a problem with the I2C transaction, it's a problem with your code. You're reading an 8 bit byte, then converting it (probably implicitly rather than explicitly) to a 32 bit int. When the high bit is 1, it's being treated as a sign bit, and extended into the upper bits of the 32-bit "equivalent". Try declaring the 8-bit variable where you initially store the value as unsigned rather than signed. If that doesn't work, post your code and you'll likely get a solution to do the conversion correctly (or avoid it all together).

Comment: Show us some of your code. it looks like you're reading the data into a 8-bit signed char variable and the sign is then being extended when you copy it into a 32-bit signed int.

Comment: I just added the code I'm using. However, I'm pretty sure that the problem is coming from the sensor because the signal I get at the scope is gotten directly from the data bus.

Comment: Is Wire.read() declared to return int8_t or uint8_t? In any case, try changing your int8_t and int16_t variables to uint8_t and uint16_t and see what happens.

Comment: I think you are not using the `available` correctly. It will be true as soon as you have 1 byte available, but you are reading 4 right away. So the first one is read correctly, the others are not. According to [this](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WireAvailable) it will return the number of the available bytes. So as a dirty solution you can check it equals or greater than `4`.

Comment: Julio, not sure if this applies to your case, but take a look at this: [When does the Arduino Wire library actually transmit on I2C ?](http://makersconfidential.blogspot.com/2015/08/when-does-arduino-wire-library-actually-transmit-on-I2C.html)

Comment: I tried with changing the variables to unsigned and it worked! Thank you all!